# Homotopy Lifting Property for the cube: tom Dieck, proposition 3.2.4.

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

This is from tom Dieck's book *Algebraic Topology*. The author uses the fact that there is a homeomorphism of pairs $k\colon (I^n\times I, (I^n\times \{0\})\cup(\partial I^n\times I))\to (I^n\times I, I^n\times \{0\})$ to prove the following theorem:

> $3.2.4$. Let $p\colon E\to B$ have HLP for the cube $I^n$. If $a\colon (I^n\times \{0\})\cup(\partial I^n\times I)\to E$ is a continuous map and $h\colon I^n\times I\to B$ a homotopy such that $h\circ i = p\circ a$ where $i\colon (I^n\times \{0\})\cup(\partial I^n\times I)\to I^n\times I$ is the inclusion, then there is a homotopy $H\colon I^n\times I\to E$ with $H\circ i = a$ and $p\circ H = h$.

However, the proof is omitted and I can't guess it. The homeomorphism $k$ comes from two following theorems proved in earlier chapters:

> $1$. Let $K \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ be a compact convex subset with nonempty interior. Then, for any $p \in \mathrm{Int}(K)$, there is a homeomorphism of pairs $(D^n, S^{n - 1})\to (K,\partial K)$ that sends $0$ to $p$.
>
> $2$. Let $\alpha\colon D^n\times I\to I$ be given by $(x,t) = \max\{2||x||, 2 - t\}$. Then $H\colon (x,t) \mapsto (((1 + t)/\alpha(x,t))x, 2 - \alpha(x,t))$ is a homeomorphism of pairs $(D^n\times I, (D^n\times \{0\})\cup (S^{n - 1}\times I))\to (D^n\times I, D^n\times \{0\})$.

Comment: If you use the relative homeomorphism $k$, then the lifting problem specified by the diagram is just the homotopy lifting property for $I^n$, which $p$ has by assumption.

Comment: @Tyrone Could you expand on this, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\require{AMScd}$

The problem is to find a diagonal for the diagram
\begin{CD}
    I^n\times 0\cup \partial I^n\times I@>a>> E\\
    @V\subseteq V V   @VV p V\\
    I^n\times I @>h>> B.
\end{CD}
Now there is a homeomorphism of pairs $k:(I^{n+1},\partial I^n\times I\cup I^n\times0)\xrightarrow\cong (I^{n+1},I^n\times 0)$, with inverse, say, $l:(I^{n+1},I^n\times 0)\xrightarrow{\cong}(I^{n+1},\partial I^n\times I\cup I^n\times0)$. If we compose the above diagram with $k$ we get a commutative diagram
\begin{CD}
    I^n\times 0@>a k|_{I^n\times0}>> E\\
    @V\subseteq V V   @VV p V\\
    I^n\times I @>h k>> B
\end{CD}
which does admit a diagonal. This is simply because the square is exactly a homotopy lifting problem for $p$, and we are assuming that $p$ has the the HLP for the space $I^n$ (the definition of the HLP is at the begining of $\S$ 3.2). Let $G:I^n\times I\rightarrow E$ be a diagonal filler, i.e. $pG=hk$ and $G|_{I^n\times0}=ak|_{I^n\times0}$.

Then returning to the first diagram we consider the map $H= G l:I^n\times I\rightarrow E$. This map satisfies
$$pH=pGl=hkl=h$$
and
$$H|_{I^n\times 0\cup \partial I^n\times I}=(Gl)|_{I^n\times 0\cup \partial I^n\times I}=G|_{I^n\times 0}l|_{I^n\times 0\cup \partial I^n\times I}=ak|_{I^n\times0}l|_{I^n\times 0\cup \partial I^n\times I}=a.$$
Hence $H$ is a filler for the first diagram.

Comment: I don't see how $k$ helps, in particular the commutativness which is all that matters, it seems to me that you shifted the problem to an other diagram which we don't know. Could you please clarify this part?

Comment: What's your definition of relative homeomorphism?

Comment: @jacopoburelli A 'homeomorphism of pairs' is the more correct terminology than my original 'relative homeomorphism'. The point of introducing $k$ is exactly to shift the problem. We are assuming the first diagram commutes (so there is no issue there), and thus the second commutes by construction. The lifting problem can be solved for the second diagram by assumption.

Comment: Then I realized you meant homeomorphism of pairs instead of relative and the commutativeness of the diagram, thanks.

Comment: @jacopoburelli no worries. Thank you for noticing my error in terminology!